# xsl:template match doesn't find matches

Tags: .net, xml, xslt

I'm trying to convert some Xaml to HTML using the .NET XslCompiledTransform and am running into difficulties getting the xslt to match Xaml tags.  For instance with this Xaml input:

```
<FlowDocument PagePadding="5,0,5,0" AllowDrop="True" NumberSubstitution.CultureSource="User" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
  <Paragraph>a</Paragraph>
</FlowDocument>
```

And this xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="FlowDocument">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Paragraph" >
    <p>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </p>
  </xsl:template>
```

I get this output:

```
<html>
    <body>
  a
</body>
</html>
```

Rather than the expected:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <p>a</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Could this be a problem with the namespace?  This is my first attempt at an xsl transform, so I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, it's a problem with the namespace.  All of the elements in your input document are in the namespace `http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation`.  Your template is trying to match elements that are in the default namespace, and it's not finding any.

You need to declare this namespace in your transform, assign it a prefix, and then use that prefix in any patterns that are intended to match elements in that namespace.  So your XSLT should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
    xmlns:p="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"/>

<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <body>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p:FlowDocument">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p:Paragraph" >
  <p>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Robert - I had tried adding the namespace to the xsl:stylesheet tag but hadn't prepended the namespace to the match field.

Answer (score 0):

It works when I remove this from your source document:

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
```

I don't believe your last two templates are matching at all.  (You can test by putting something like a wrapping <div> in your FlowDocument template.)

Comment: The FlowDocument comes directly from a WPF RichTextBox, so I'd rather handle it in the xslt than by manipulating the source.  Adding the namespace and qualifying the element match fields fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just try changing

"xsl:template match='/'"

tag in your xsl file with

"xsl:template match='*'"

This should give you the desired output.