# xsl transformation (xslt) issue with cdata

Tags: xslt, cdata

I have a problem with XSLT Transformation.

I have an XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parser xmlns="http://www.dabgps.nxp">
  <bash>
    <![CDATA[
      # MAIN VARIABLES
     bash
    ]]>
  </bash>

  <bbb>
    <![CDATA[
      # MAIN VARIABLES
      bbb
    ]]>
  </bbb>

  <bash>
    <![CDATA[
      # MAIN VARIABLES
      bash
    ]]>
  </bash>
</parser>
```

And I have a XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="parser">

  <xsl:value-of select="bbb"/>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem I get every time a result:

```
  # MAIN VARIABLES
  bash





  # MAIN VARIABLES
  bbb





  # MAIN VARIABLES
  bash
```

What I expect is of course only:

```
  # MAIN VARIABLES
  bbb
```

Doesn't matter which  or  it is.
The XSLT processor print out all the stuff I have in CDATA Tag, even if it is not in the matched template (seems just to get CDATA out of the document)
What could be here wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is here related to namespace http://www.dabgps.nxp defined in your XML file.
There is a similar thread that is explaining about this here.

[xsl:template match doesn't find matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273199/xsltemplate-match-doesnt-find-matches)